# Why variables should be assigned with ".Value" when using ByRef?

Tags: variables, powershell

What is the difference between:

```
$A="Something"
```

and

```
$A.Value="Something"
```

I see that this is working only when `.Value` is used:

```
function main
{
    $A="Original A"
    $B="Original B"

    SetByRef1 ([ref]$A)
    SetByRef2 ([ref]$B)

    $A
    $B

    #output: Changed A
    #output: Original B
}


function SetByRef1([ref]$A)
{
    $A.Value = "Changed A"
}

function SetByRef2([ref]$B)
{
    $B = "Changed B"
}

main
```

I guess, that `$B = "Changed B"` is defining a new variable B, whereas `$A.Value = "Changed A"` is just changing the content but I haven't found a confirmation for that.

Comment: The answer you are looking for should be in [About_Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847792.aspx). Using the `.Value` when attempting to change the object is just a fact it seems. The type goes from a string to a `System.Management.Automation.PSReference` while in the `SetByRef1` fyi.

Comment: Is this really just like in C++ when you use the dereferencing operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using reference variables in functions you must use the `.Value` to interact with the original object as seen in [About_Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847792.aspx)

```
PS C:\ps-test> function double
>> {
>>     param ([ref]$x) $x.value = $x.value * 2
>> }
```

If you examine the object while inside the function you can sort of see the difference. Inside the function `SetByRef1` I added the following lines.

```
$a.GetType().FullName
$a.value.GetType().FullName
```

Which nets the following output.

```
System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
System.String
```

The type of `$a.value` shows that you are acting on the original object.