# When using a string that's passed by reference in powershell, how do you access its value?

Tags: string, powershell, types, pass-by-reference

My question applies to passing a `String` type by reference to a PowerShell function.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744681/why-variables-should-be-assigned-with-value-when-using-byref) they set the `.Value` of a variable that is passed by reference so that its value persists after the function exits.

If however you want to access/read the `.Value` that the reference points to, do you use its argument name in the function, by itself, or do you use its `.Value` property?

In the code below I'd like the `$whichMenu` string argument to persist it's value after exiting the function, but I'd also like to access / read it, in the function.

I don't know if the `.Value` acts like the dereferencing operator in C++ or not.

```
Function displayMenu($funcHash, [String][ref]$whichMenu, $storeName, $startRange, $endRange) {

    do {
        # TODO: Display Reg Range: $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = ""
        # Display a Menu
        cls
        Write-Host "whichFunc: $($whichFunc)"           
        Write-Host "$($storeName) | $($startRange) - $($endRange)"
        Write-Host "-------------------------------------"
        Write-Host ""

        $funcHash[$whichMenu].Keys | sort | %{ 
            Write-Host -NoNewLine $_ 
            Write-Host -NoNewLine "."

            $subHash = $funcHash[$whichMenu][$_]

            Write-Host " " $subHash["label"]
        }

        Write-Host "-------------------------------------"
        Write-Host "1:common|2:drivers|3:netmask|4:printer|5:display"               
        Write-Host "-------------------------------------"

        $whichFunc = queryUserCommon $dasIntOptions "Pick a function: " 


        if($menuKeys -contains $whichMenu) {
          $whichMenu.Value = "" + $whichFunc 
        }

        Write-Host "whichFunc: $($whichFunc)"
        Write-Host "actionKeys $($actionKeys)"
                    Write-Host "$($actionKeys -contains $whichFunc)"

        Write-Host "whichMenu: $($whichMenu)"
        Write-Host "menuKeys: $($menuKeys)"
        Write-Host "$($menuKeys -notcontains $whichMenu)"

    } while($actionKeys -notcontains $whichFunc)

    return $whichFunc
}
```

Comment: The linked question answers yours; you use `.value` whenever you want to interact with the original object that was passed by reference (`[ref]`).

Comment: Personally, I find the [`[Ref]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6) very confusing and far from elegant. As hash tables (objects) are passed by reference by default, I often use a [`HashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6), e.g. `[HashTable]$Ref = @{}` as parameter and then call `-Ref @{whichMenu = $whichMenu}`. To change the value from whitin the function will be: `$Ref.whichMenu = 'Hello World'`

Comment: You cannot cast as a `[string]` (or other value type ) any variable which is already cast as a reference i.e. defined with type `[ref]`. Use `Function displayMenu($funcHash, [ref]$whichMenu, …`.

Comment: @JosefZ I tried it, and when I called it with `displayMenu $funcHash $blah "bob" 1` I got `displayMenu : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'whichMenu'. Reference type is expected in argument.`

Comment: Call it as `displayMenu $funcHash ([ref]$blah) "bob" 1`

Comment: @JosefZ  Thanks! That did the trick.  I can pass it by reference now.